# How to provide administrative privileges to a windows folder

Tags: winforms, installshield, setup-deployment

I have created setup of windows desktop application using with Install shield (http://www.installshield.com/) in Visual studio 2012 but I don't see there any provision how to provide administrative privileges to folder in free version of install shield.
When running application client side, it not able to run without administrative privileges .

Any !dea about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only free deployment tool with full featured support for all aspects of deployment is [**Wix**](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Comment: Hello Glytzhkof, Thanks let me try it and know you shortly.

Comment: [First Google hit](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ConfiguringPrmssnsFile.htm).

Comment: If an application requires access to folders that its users cannot access, it is broken and should be fixed. But yes, the limited edition doesn't offer support for changing folder permissions.

Comment: Yes Michael, I know limited version don't offer to change permissions. does it any third party software or programmatically can change permissions.

Comment: If you just require write access to a config file, the correct approach would be to write it to the user profile. If not, just open write access for that single file.

Comment: It looks like the same nonsense of installing to the ProgramFiles folder and then finding out that a limited user can't write to that folder. Fix the app to use user appdata for those files, that's why it's got that name.

Comment: Hello Michael,Can you send me guideline how to make setup with Wix tools.

Comment: Hello PhilDW, I am able to install setup through appdata but when I am installing with standard user then asking for Admin user password. How can I escape not entering admin password and standard user should allow to install setup without admin password.

Comment: I conquered this issue by a tricky way. I copied database files (xml files) to root folder created through program run time and provide privileges after creating folder along with copied stuff. right now I am working in the right way, In future, I can plan more managed way.